# Python - PDF form that fills in certain fields based on the value of another field

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I am currently trying to use the canvas feature of `reportlab.pdfgen` to create a PDF form for a user to fill out.  I would like to set up the form so that some of the fields are filled in automatically based on what the user enters for a previous field.  For example, I have one **choice** field created as such:

```
my_options = [' ', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
    form.choice(
        name='acctype',
        tooltip='Type of Account',
        x=290,
        y=645,
        borderStyle='inset',
        width=200,
        height=20,
        fillColor=white,
        forceBorder=True,
        fontName='Helvetica-Bold',
        options=my_options
    )
```

Lets say the user selects option 'A' for this field and there are multiple text fields that I have created after this field.  I would like to have these fields automatically fill in based on what the user chooses for the above field, in this case 'A'.  Is there a way to somehow store the value of this field in a variable and then use that to map the values of the other fields that depend on this field?

I just started using reportlab and any help is appreciated.  I'm not sure if this is possible and if it isn't, is there another way you would recommend going about solving this?

I tried searching for ways to store the value of the field so that I could fill in the other fields based on the response of the first field.